# I'm having trouble getting a div to take the width of the entire screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

No matter what I try, there is still a visible margin between the div and the top/right/left of the screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test2.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid" id="topBackground">
        <h1>first</h1>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#topBackground{
background-color:#310048;
height:500px;
float:auto;
margin:0 auto;
max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: remove the margin from the `h1`

Comment: Bootstrap appears to not load properly. I am getting the error: "Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute"

Comment: You are not inlcuding bootstrap correctly, verify the link, this is your issue ... and there is not `float:auto` and you don't need max-width:100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Header has default margin so you have to remove it and also set body margin: 0 auto;

```
body{
    margin: 0 auto;

}
#topBackground{
  padding:0;
background-color:#310048;
height:500px;
float:auto;
margin:0 auto;
max-width:100%;
}
h1{
  margin:0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rghhwrm5/

Comment: By default bootstrap is supposed to set the body's margin to 0, so this should not be necessary. See my comment on OP

Comment: @ACSND sorry but i don't agree with this, the issue is that bootstrap is not loading ! that's it ... no need to add margin 0 to body or remove margin from h1